# Add more layers in seq2seq model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, layer, seq2seq

In the sample [seq2seq](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py) code given by fchollet, how can I add more LSTM layers to the encoder and decoder? I'm having some trouble with the shapes and a bit confused in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keras' functional api lets you call layers. This lets you chain another layer on top the output of an existing layer by calling it. For example here:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(encoder(encoder_inputs))
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting this error - ValueError: Layer lstm_2 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM object at 0x00000261B7AD2B38>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm having same problem. Specifically during inference, how do we reconstruct decoder

Comment: @AmelMusic Yes, It works, if you do it carefully. I've defined something like: c1, h1, c2, h2, etc ... for 2 layers of LSTM. Also make sure you set "return_sequences" to True for first layers. Read the docs about "Model()" too, that helped me to understand what's going on. (Unfortunately my code was too long and confusing, so instead I decided to describe what I did, and It worked.)